# How can I share image from website on Telegram?

Tags: php, html, telegram

I want to share only image from a website on Telegram but shared image contains URL too

```html
<a target="_blank" class="telegram-btn"
    href='https://telegram.me/share/url?url=Imageurl '>
    <i class="fa fa-telegram icon-telegram-blog"></i>
</a>
```

Is there any way to share only image without image URL?

Comment: What is the purpose of sending image to chat? Maybe you can use bots for that?

Comment: @wowkin2    I want to share users picture on telegram

Comment: users can share picture by uploading it directly. Or you can create bot like t.me/gif to choose image from inline search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't share only image. As you can see in [Telegram documentation](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share) this button is for sharing URLs. Side effect from it is that Telegram can show a preview for given URL, but it can't send image without URL.